# load javascript file and call a function inside it using C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to load javascript file on the click of a button and at the same time want to call a function inside that file.
I am using below code on button click, But it is not working.

```
if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("jQuery"))
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", ResolveClientUrl("js/getmap.js"));
    String strscript = "<script language='javascript'>GetMap();</script>";
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("clientScript"))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "clientScript", strscript);
    }
}
```

GetMap() is a function inside getmap.js. Thanks

Comment: What's not working? The file's not being loaded? The function isn't getting called?

Comment: When I reformated your source code, I added two missing curly braces. Could they be the resons for your trouble?

Comment: I tried   if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("jQuery"))
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", ResolveClientUrl("js/getmap.js"));            
            
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upCollapse, typeof(UpdatePanel), upCollapse.ClientID, "GetMap();", true);

Comment: And added my aspx code for map inside update panel using asynchronous post back trigger.upCollapse is my updatepanel ID.